# Insert selected values from one Table to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to get the information from my table that contains info about my books, and store it into a database called Orders when you press "Add to cart". But I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. Ive searched all over and tried everything I can think of, so there is obv something I dont know. Can you please help me correct this statement to give it the decired effect?

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)"+ 
                                 "SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfo"+
                                 "WHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id", con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: hey iQue the tables Orders and BooksInfo reside in the same database. right? I am asking because as I was reading your questions it seems a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes they are in the same database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price) "+ 
                                 "SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price "+
                                 "FROM BooksInfo "+
                                 "WHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id", con);
```

Comment: This gave me an error at `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` , An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: I am sorry iQue. The "VALUES" was not needed. I removed it. Please try this one now.

Comment: Haha, no need to apologize for trying to help. Seems Ive made some sort of mistake in my tables since this give me the error "Cant insert duplicate keys in to Orders". Will try to figure out what is causing that and see if this works :)

Comment: Fixed, Problem was that I was using ISBN as primary key and obv cant have duplicate primary Ids. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't look like you've gotten very far but you need spaces at the end of your strings when you concatenate

```
                         // note addition of space to end of each string fragment
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price) "+ 
                                 "SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfo "+
                                 "WHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id", con);
```

Otherwise your SQL statement would be:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfoWHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id
```

Which would be a syntax error since there is no whitespace between the column list and the `SELECT` keyword

Some other things I see:

- Is there not an OrderID on the Orders table?
- Why do you need the Title and Author in the `Order` table?  Ideally those should be foreign keys to `BooksInfo`
- Shouldn't Order Items be in a separate table? (what if someone orders two books?)

Comment: Order items are in a seperate table? that is why Im trying to insert infro about the ordered book in to this table

Comment: @iQue Typically you have an `Order` table which contains data about the order itself (date placed, status, address, etc.) and a _separate_  table that contains the actual items within each order.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. And that does make more sense, but currently I am just following orders from an assignmemt :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have the @Id parameter in the insert statement so the ID parameter is redundant.

Also, to insert the values you would need the corresponding `Values (@ISBN, @Title, @Author, @Price)` statement with the Insert statement. Then you will also need the parameters added with value in a similar fashion to how you have done the ID one.

As per the comment below, the SQL would become:

```
insert into DatabaseA..Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price) 
SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price from DatabaseB..BooksInfo
where BooksInfo.ISBN = @Id
```

if you wanted to control the databases from C# then you can add these in as part of the string instead of hard coding them.

Comment: But that would be to add values using variables, Im looking for a way to insert from one DB to another without saving the values in to variables first, there must be a way, no?

Comment: In that case, if your databases are named DatabaseA and DatabaseB then you can use something like this:
insert into DatabaseA..Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)
SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price from DatabaseB..BookInfo

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate this task on two different tasks
 1. SELECTing values from one database and put them into some object orderCart;
 2. INSERTing or update values in other database with the values of orderCart
Firstly - it is more easy to debug and understand a code in that case

Answer (score 0):

it's about string concatenation.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)"+ 
                                 "SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfo"+
                                 "WHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id", con);
```

SqlCommand will produce

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfoWHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id
```

instead

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ISBN, Title, Author, Price)
SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM BooksInfo
WHERE BooksInfo.ISBN=@Id
```

you can add space or linebreak after price) and BooksInfo